# JQuery how to acces td tag of row

Tags: jquery

i have list selected rows in table: `var items = $('.trSelected',$('#formTable'));`

My question is how to access each td tag in list if items (selected rows)?

Comment: Please provide your html

Comment: FYI you can get better performance by not creating an entirely new jQuery object in the context, try this: `var items = $('.trSelected', '#formTable');`

Comment: I'm new in jquery so i'm still learnign :). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `each` jQuery function to loop every row you got and select its `td` elements:

```
items.each(function(i, k) {
    var tds = $(this).find("td");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var items = $('.trSelected', '#formTable'));

items.each(function () {
    $td = $("td", $this);
    // Now do what you like with $td...
});
```

Adding `$this` as a second parameter on the selector gives jQuery a context in which to search the DOM. Here `$this` is each `<tr>` from your first selector and jQuery will only look inside that element.